# How to get around 403 errors on websites with text-based browsers?

Tags: command-line, lynx, w3m

The issue seems to stem from a misconfigured web server and has affected some domains I've came across in `lynx` and `w3m`, but `links` can access at least in some instances. Can this be resolved on the user-side?

```
403 Forbidden
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nginx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your text web browsers User Agent to something modern, e.g.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0`

on lynx this is done using `--useragent` option like

```
lynx -useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
```

Comment: `lynx -useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"` resolved the issue ([docs](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html)), you could edit this in.

Comment: OK, I corrected for lynx.